# What is Ougi reading on her phone when she meets Araragi at the steps to the shrine?

Tags: monogatari-series

When Araragi and Yotsugi land at the base of the steps to the shrine in episode 3 of Tsukimonogatari, we see that Ougi is waiting there, reading something on her phone.

[image: Ougi reading a thing on her phone]

What's she reading? Is it plot-relevant?

Answer (score 6):

Ougi is reading Franz Kafka's ***The Metamorphosis*** (in the original German, *Die Verwandlung*; in Japanese, 「変身」). She's at the very end of the story. The portion displayed on screen is the equivalent of the following (from the translation by Ian Johnston [available on Wikibooks](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis)) (spoiler alert!):

> ...which was extremely favorable and with especially promising prospects. The greatest improvement in their situation at this moment, of course, had to come from a change of dwelling. Now they wanted to rent an apartment smaller and cheaper but better situated and generally more practical than the present one, which Gregor had found. While they amused themselves in this way, it struck Mr. and Mrs. Samsa almost at the same moment how their daughter, who was getting more animated all the time, had blossomed recently, in spite of all the troubles which had made her cheeks pale, into a beautiful and voluptuous young woman. Growing more silent and almost unconsciously understanding each other in their glances, they thought that the time was now at hand to seek out a good honest man for her. And it was something of a confirmation of their new dreams and good intentions when at the end of their journey the daughter first lifted herself up and stretched her young body.

Why specifically *The Metamorphosis*? Beats me. Perhaps it's that Ougi identifies with Samsa, being a monstrous and verminous creature him/her/itself.

Comment: The title of the novel might be a reference to Ougi herself, since she has at least 3 forms (as a girl before April Year +1, as a boy after April, and as "Darkness").